# Deployment of general files to Windows XP Pro clients

Tags: windows-xp, installation, remote

I'm looking into deploying general software projects to small networks of Windows XP Pro/7 Pro machines.

A use case is that there are 3 client machines and a build server. The build server builds 3 separate installer packages, one for each client (they are all slightly different). When a new build is ready I would like the installers to be deployed and executed on each respective client.

My question is what is the cleanest way to automatically push / pull installers to the client machines and run them, considering that I want to keep the client machines as virgin as possible?

Details:

- Machines are Windows XP / 7 Pro
- installer used is Inno Setup
- Build server is Hudson running on Linux box with Windows slave

Thanks for thinking with me

Brian

Comment: A few questions: 1) What kind of installers are they? 2) Is this the only use case, or do you have cases where there are more clients? 3) Are you looking for immediate deployment when the builds are finished?

Comment: Installers are Inno Setup packages. There could be many more clients, depends on the project. And it is preferable that the system updates when the build server updates

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with a logon script. If you want more details, more information is needed (does the installer file name changes between version ? How do you differentiate between installers ?)

Comment: These machines will be left on 24 hours a day, Login/Out will happen infrequently. 

Installer filenames do not have versions added.

And differentiating between installers is an open question.